How do I swap surround's spacing for opening vs. closing delimeters?
I use vim-surround all day, and it's a constant annoyance to me that I have to reach a little bit farther to hit the closing delimiter when I don't want spaces around the delimited content (which is 100% of the time).
With the cursor inside the word hello,

ysiw( results in ( hello ), and
ysiw) results in (hello).

I always want (2), which is harder to type, and I never use (1).
How do I swap the commands?

You can use iwb as an alias for iw):
ysiwb

Same for iwB versus iw}, and iwr versus iw].
FWIW, iwb and iwB are inspired by ib and iB, which also exist in Vim itself. They are not strictly equivalent because Surround's iw( and iw) work differently, whereas Vim's i( and i) work the same, but the difference is meaningless in practice. See :help ib.
I don't know the exact history of the non-standard *r variants but it has been picked up by a number of plugin authors over the years. Since I prefer the *b/*B variants anyway, I have had the following in my config for a while, which lets me use ir/ar for i[/a[ as if they were standard:
xnoremap ir i[
onoremap ir :<C-u>execute 'normal v' . v:count1 . 'i['<CR>
xnoremap ar a[
onoremap ar :<C-u>execute 'normal v' . v:count1 . 'a['<CR>


In other words, the targets b and B do the right thing.

@D.BenKnoble, this is even better than the thing I asked for. Thanks!

Using the tip in :help surround-customizing, we can do
let g:surround_{char2nr('(')} = "(\r)"
let g:surround_{char2nr(')')} = "( \r )"

I haven't tested how this plays with the yS variants, but it worked for words and other less-than-full-line tests I did.
